# Windows Terminal : Split pane with different root path (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, terminal, splitpane

I'm currently using Windows Terminal with PowerShell, and I wanted to find a solution for remembering the different terminals created between sessions, as the internal Visual Studio command-line tool doesn't provide this functionality (If it does, I'm all ears :))

To achieve this, I attempted to build a script in Windows Terminal that would create a new tab and split it into three sections, each with a different root. Here's the script I tried alongside the error log :

```
$frontendPath = "C:\Path_Example\frontend"
$backendPath = "C:\Path_Example\backend"
$rootPath = "C:\Path_Example"

$command = "wt ; split-pane -p 'pwsh -NoExit -Command `""cd '$frontendPath'; pwsh`""" +
           " ; split-pane -H -p 'pwsh -NoExit -Command `""cd '$backendPath'; pwsh`""" +
           " ; split-pane -H -p 'pwsh -NoExit -Command `""cd '$rootPath'; pwsh`"""

Start-Process -FilePath wt.exe -ArgumentList "-d", ".", "-e", $command
```

```
At C:\Users\speak\split.ps1:5 char:58
+ $command = "wt ; split-pane -p 'pwsh -NoExit -Command `""cd '$fronten ...
+                                                          ~~
Unexpected token 'cd' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\speak\split.ps1:6 char:59
+            " ; split-pane -H -p 'pwsh -NoExit -Command `""cd '$backen ...
+                                                           ~~
Unexpected token 'cd' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\speak\split.ps1:7 char:59
+            " ; split-pane -H -p 'pwsh -NoExit -Command `""cd '$rootPa ...
+                                                           ~~
Unexpected token 'cd' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

As you can see, I'm not very experienced with scripting, so I sought help from ChatGPT. Unfortunately, despite trying different prompts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. If anyone could provide some guidance or help me troubleshoot, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `wt.exe`, despite being the [*CLI*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments) of Windows Terminal, is a GUI-subsystem application and therefore launches *asynchronously* by default; therefore, you can invoke it *directly* - no need for [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)
- [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) 7+ CLI, has a `-WorkingDirectory` (`-wd`) parameter.
- More generally, as [Mehrdad Qasemkhani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795577/mehrdad-qasemkhani) points out, `wt.exe` itself has a `--startingDirectory` (`-d`) parameter that allows specifying a startup working directory, irrespective of what shell is being launched.

Therefore:

- Using `-d` (`--startingDirectory`) in combination with an explicit shell executable (`pwsh`):

  ```bash
  wt.exe -d $frontEndPath pwsh `; split-pane -H -d $backendPath pwsh `; split-pane -H -d $rootPath pwsh
  ```
- If your *default* profile is `pwsh`, `-d` *alone* is enough:

  ```bash
  wt.exe -d $frontEndPath `; split-pane -H -d $backendPath `; split-pane -H -d $rootPath
  ```
- Alternatively, using `pwsh`'s `-wd` (`-WorkingDirectory`) parameter:

  ```bash
  wt.exe pwsh -wd $frontEndPath `; split-pane -H pwsh -wd $backendPath `; split-pane -H pwsh -wd $rootPath
  ```

This **opens a *new* Windows Terminal window with a single tab** split horizontally into 3 panes, each running a PowerShell (Core) instance with the specified directory as the current location (working directory).

Note the need to escape `;` as `` `; ``, so that PowerShell doesn't interpret it as its statement separator.

---

If you want to **open the new tab in an *existing* window**, more work is needed:

- `-w 0` targets the most recently active window
- however, that window isn't automatically *activated* (if there is a way to do that via options, do let us know).

```bash
$frontendPath = 'C:\'
$backendPath = 'C:\Windows'
$rootPath = 'C:\Users'

# Get the PID (process ID) of what is presumed to be the most
# recently active window, if any.
$existingPid = (Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore WindowsTerminal | Select-Object -Last 1).Id

# -w 0 targets the most recently active window, if any.
wt.exe -w 0 -d $frontEndPath pwsh `; split-pane -H -d $backendPath pwsh `; split-pane -H -d $rootPath pwsh `; ft 0

# If a preexisting window was targeted, it must now be activated explicitly.
if ($existingPid) { 
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate($existingPid)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working ! 
Would it be possible to open it in a new tab instead of a new window ?
Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @InfectedJapanese; my pleasure. Please see my update re creating the tab in a preexisting window.